# json() on "requests" response raises UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, python-requests

I'm querying Github's Jobs API with python3, using the `requests` library, but running into an error parsing the response.

Library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

**Code:**

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?' 

response = requests.get(url)

print(response.json())
```

**Error:**

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in
>   position 321: ordinal not in range(128)

Using this API in the past with Ruby, I've never run into this issue.

I also tried converting it to a dictionary but it resulted in the same errors.

There's other questions on SO about the `UnicodeEncodeError` (mostly re: opening files), but I'm not familiar with Python and didn't find them helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the response is actually JSON. Try printing `response.text` and see if it looks like a valid JSON object.

Assuming it is JSON: it's very "hack"-ey, but you can replace the non ASCII characters with their escaped Unicode representation:

```
def escape_unicode(c):
    return c.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace').decode('ascii')

response = ...

text = response.text
escaped = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', lambda m: escape_unicode(m.group(0)), text)
json_response = json.loads(escaped)
```